# Overlapping elements in HTML

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an index page for a dummy website which has a header followed by a couple of blocks displaying previews of posts. There are two problems I am facing.

My `header` element overlaps with the following `div`'s. Following suggestions I got from stackoverflow, I wrapped the `header` and following `div` elements inside a wrapper `div`. But that didn't help. I have made a fiddle to explain the problem [here](https://jsfiddle.net/liquidus08/ott9qxq2). How do I tackle this?

The issue I am facing is that- if you look at the `header` element, you'll see that it is offset from the top and left by a few pixels. I used `width:100%` along with `margin` and `padding` as `0px`. If I add the following to the `header`, the issue gets resolved.

```
position:absolute;
left:0px;
top: 0px;
```

But I'm reluctant on using the `position` attribute as I have had difficulties working with them. Is there any other way to have the `header` element start right off the corners

Comment: You don't want the header to overlapp the content is that right?

Comment: @Alberto yes. and I need it to start from the top left cormer

Answer (score 2):

Add margin:0; to body and h1

```
body {
  margin : 0;
}
.page_header {
    background-color:rgba(146,0,0,0.8);
    font-weight:500;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size:30px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    display:block;
}
h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ott9qxq2/1/

Comment: Sorry i mentioned wrong jsfiddle in answer before. Plz check updated answer

Answer (score 0):

- Remove unnecessary css of `.page_header`. here i have commented those lines
- Set `margin: 0;` and `padding: 0` to `body`
- Remove margin of `h1` in `page_header`

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.page_header {
    /* position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top: 0px; */
    background-color:rgba(146,0,0,0.8);
    font-weight:500;
    font-family:Roboto;
    font-size:30px;
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    /* height: 100px; */
    display:block;
}
.page_header h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
.post_preview{
    display:block;
    width: 60%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    text-align:left;
}

.post_preview_img{
    height: 100px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 0px;
}
.post_preview_header{
    font-size:24px;
    font-family:Roboto;
    color: rgba(8,8,8,0.60);;
    font-weight:200;
}
.post_preview_dt{
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family:Verdana;
    color:rgba(64,64,64,0.60);
}
.post_preview_txt{
    font-size:16px;
    font-family:Roboto;
    color:rgba(64,64,64,0.50);
}

.post_preview:hover{
    background-color: rgba(240,240,240, 0.75)
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,400i,500,700&subset=latin,vietnamese,latin-ext,cyrillic,greek,cyrillic-ext,greek-ext"
          rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<div>
    <header class = 'page_header'>
        <h1>Notes on Machine Learning</h1>
    </header>
    <div class = 'post_preview'>
        <img src = "" class = 'post_preview_img'/>
        <h3 class = 'post_preview_header'>K Means ++ as an initialization algorithm</h3>
        <p class = 'post_preview_dt'>19 May 2018</p>
        <p class = 'post_preview_txt'>Results of K Means depends on the initialized cluster values. Is there a smarter way to do it?</p>
    </div>

    <div class = 'post_preview'>
        <img src = "" class = 'post_preview_img'/>
        <h3 class = 'post_preview_header'>Missing Value Imputation using K Nearest Neighbors</h3>
        <p class = 'post_preview_dt'>19 May 2018</p>
        <p class = 'post_preview_txt'>Like common cold, missing values appear everywhere. </p>
    </div>

    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if this answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark and upvote. 
This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. 
There is no obligation to do this. :) @Clock Slave